# Get Jobject property asp.net mvc

Tags: json, api, asp.net-mvc-4

Im stuck with i little problem.

I using a API to get data from servers reponse about the weather.
The response i Json wich is nice.

The Json:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"sys":{"type":3,"id":60992,"message":0.0067,"country":"GB","sunrise":1420358723,"sunset":1420387545},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":275.05,"humidity":95,"pressure":1035.7,"temp_min":275.05,"temp_max":275.05},"wind":{"speed":2.82,"deg":178.5},"clouds":{"all":64},"dt":1420400811,"id":2634341,"name":"City of Westminster","cod":200}
```

I can get the json data from the following line:

```
"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}]
```

My code:

```
        var json = JObject.Parse(rawJson);
        var result = json["weather"];
        var data = new List<TheWeather>();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
        {
            var desc = (string)result[i]["description"];


            data.Add(new TheWeather(desc));
        }

        return data;
```

but now i want to retrieve the "name" propertie from this line witch i placed i the end of the acctual Json object.
this line does not any propertie  the one im retrieving just above.
This line is between the json start end brackets.
**Minified json object example:**

```
   {"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"sys":{"type":3,"id":60992,"message":0.0067,"country":"GB","sunrise":1420358723,"sunset":1420387545} "name":"City of Westminster","cod":200}
```

How can i get the "name" from this json object?
please help!